# Identificando caminho do arquivo com pathinfo

Tags: php

Bom montei uma função no arquivo local.php:

```
function Local() {

    $path_parts = pathinfo( __FILE__ );
    $arquivo = "".$path_parts['dirname']."/".$path_parts['basename'];

    return $arquivo;
}
```

Chamo a função no arquivo index.php assim:

```
include "local.php";

echo Local();
```

O problema e que ela esta me retornando o caminho do arquivo da função, e eu preciso que ela me retorne o caminho do arquivo index.php.

Alguém sabe o que eu estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a global $_SERVER para exibir o caminho do arquivo em execução.

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']
```

No caso da sua função, ficaria apenas:

```
function Local() {
    return $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
}
```

Comment: da sua forma deu certo, porém se eu chamo a função em um arquivo, e chamo esse arquivo dentro de outro com um 'include', o caminho que me retorna não é do arquivo onde esta sendo chamado a função. Preciso identificar o arquivo onde a função é chamada, independente se ele é colocado em um include dentro de outro arquivo. Conseguiu entender minha explicação?